# Update the image in folder using REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email, content-builder

Im using a rest api to upload images or text in marketing cloud content builder, i have created a folder inside the content builder(folder name: Content Area) and i want to push the data inside this folder. Any idea on how to push the content inside a folder in content builder?

Comment: To verify. The file already exists inside of Content Builder and are looking to move locations. And not to upload a new file into this folder?

Comment: No, we need to push new file inside the folder @Gortonington

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a new asset inside of Contact Builder utilizing the REST API, you will need to use the [POST /asset/v1/content/assets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm#detail_CreateAsset) endpath.

This will require you to provide a JSON with all the values you wish to utilize for your image (including the image value itself).  One of these values is **"Category" which is actually the folder location of the file**.  Inside of Category, you would need to place the CategoryID of your folder - which can be found inside of the UI or via API.

For more information on Asset Modeling, please see the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/asset-model.htm).

Comment: thanks @gortonington, i retrieved the category id using API but while push the asset where to add the cat id?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/categories.htm

Comment: got it @gortonington