# Cloudpage form upload an image into the content builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, upload, cloudpage

Is it possible to create a cloudpage form with an input field that upload for example an image into the content builder?

Regards,
Martijn

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to create a kind of wizard to upload content, from my experience that is not possible using CloudPages. Maybe creating a [Custom Activity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Rest API, not possible in a cloud page form.

Check the link:

[Update the image in folder using REST API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224470/update-the-image-in-folder-using-rest-api)